# My WordPress featured image is not showing up on Facebook post and with Tweets

Tags: html, wordpress, image, social-media

I've tinkered with the possibility that one of my plugins were messing up the featured image. Did not work.
I checked on FB debug tool this was the error message:

Invalid Image Content Type
Provided og:image URL, https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png could not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.

[image: screenshot of the debug tool results]

I've tried reuploading the same picture but with a different type like png and jpg, didn't work too.

this is the detailed part, I tried to look at the og tags, but they're all correct, nothing's out of place.

```
<!-- Search Engine Optimization by Rank Math - https://s.rankmath.com/home -->
<title>Services | Codex Shopper</title>
<meta name="description" content="Codex Shopper Free Business Listing, express your business the way you want others to feel, submit business for review.">
<meta name="robots" content="follow, index, max-snippet:-1, max-video-preview:-1, max-image-preview:large">
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.codexshopper.com/services/">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="og:type" content="article">
<meta property="og:title" content="Services | Codex Shopper">
<meta property="og:description" content="Codex Shopper Free Business Listing, express your business the way you want others to feel, submit business for review.">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.codexshopper.com/services/">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Codex Shopper">
<meta property="og:updated_time" content="2020-11-14T04:16:17+00:00">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png">
<meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="300">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="300">
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="Free Business Listing">
<meta property="og:image:type" content="image/png">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Services | Codex Shopper">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Codex Shopper Free Business Listing, express your business the way you want others to feel, submit business for review.">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@@Marketerextrao1">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@@Marketerextrao1">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png">
<script type="application/ld+json" class="rank-math-schema">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I had to go on cPanel -_-, disable the hotlink protection. It was the one messing up my site.

Answer (score 0):

I don't sure that this work for your problem, but try using of Yoast plugin to provide og:image without problem.

In same problem, **I was forced to change Url Name (Slug) to it work**

And if your meta content is real, attention to this that your link of image throw this error:

```
https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png
Oops! That page can’t be found.
```

Comment: the picture shows up on my end fine using this "https://www.codexshopper.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/codexs.png", because I'm logged in. I'm using RankMath right now, but let me try using Yoast instead.

Comment: Did you change you url slug?

Comment: if with url slug didn't work, try to disable your plugins one by one to find out the problem, I may help you to find the problem, but my experience says with each disabling, change the slug! and this so bad :(

Comment: yes, changed it, didn't work. Right now if this doesn't get fixed I'm thinking of wiping my website clean and starting from the bottom.

Comment: let me try and run it again with 1 by 1 disabled plugins to find out what went wrong.

Comment: I tried deactivating the plugins one by one, didn't work.

Comment: Do you have any error in development tools? Like mixed content or any other?

Comment: Nope, didn't get any errors. I tried running a diagnose, tried to check on my database too. Got rid of the extra photos imagify was making on backup folders, didn't work either.